# Strikethrough to the custom VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that helps me to record multiple dates in one cell stacked however I couldnt figure out how the 2nd and further entries have the strikethrough to show that date has been changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.CountLarge = 1 And Target.Column = 1 Then
If Len(Target.Value) > 0 Then
  Target.Offset(, 1).Value = Target.Value & _
                             IIf(Len(Target.Offset(, 1).Value), Chr(10), _
                             "") & Target.Offset(, 1).Value & 
 Target.Offset(, 1)            
   End If
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why the `...  & Target.Offset(, 1).Value &  Target.Offset(, 1)`? Shouldn't one  Target.Offset(, 1).Value be enough?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the length of the string that you want to NOT be strikethrough, you can use the following, replacing the 6 with your length:

```
With ActiveCell
    With .Characters(6, Len(.Value) - (6 - 1))
        .Font.Strikethrough = True
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Good catch. I couldn't understand what the op was attempting to convey but I'm pretty sure you picked up the intent.

Answer (score 2):

Without working through [Terry Field](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5623340/terry-field)'s interpretation, I would never have understood your intent but there are still a few points to make.

- When writing values to the worksheet within a Worksheet_Change, always suspend event handling or the event driven sub procedure will try to run on top of itself.
- Whenever possible, deal with multiple Target cells rather than exiting the Worksheet_Change whenever more than a single Target is changed.
- You appear to be dealing with dates in column A so use .Text rather than .Value or .Value2 in order to capture the dates as they appear on the worksheet.
- This may be minor but there is no reason to .Strikethrough the vbLF so the .Strikethrough should start at the length of Target + 1 and continue to the end of the cell's displayed value.

Revised Worksheet_Change code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo meh
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim l As Long, ol As Long, t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("A:A"))
            If CBool(Len(t.Value2)) Then
                l = Len(t.Text)
                With t.Offset(0, 1)
                    .Value = t.Text & _
                        IIf(CBool(Len(.Value2)), vbLF & t.Offset(0, 1).Text, vbNullString)
                    .Characters(l + 1, ol).Font.Strikethrough = True
                End With
                t.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
            End If
        Next t
    End If

meh:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, this is a much more complete answer than mine, thanks.  I was just pointing in the right direction but this should be perfect

Comment: Thank you so much everyone that is what I wanted!